# How to use pagination and sort with Comparator class

Tags: java, spring, sorting, pagination

i've got a problem. I am using pagination and sorting in my project. But now i would like to sort not just by one field but something more complex. That is why i tried to do something like this:

```
PageRequest.of(pageNo.orElse(0), pageSize, Sort.by(Comparator.comparing(this::daysFilter)).ascending())
```

But Sort just can't take this :(

Is there another way ? Or am i doing something wrong ?

What is my alternative ? What else can i do ?

This is Boolean i want to have my list sorted by:

```
 private Boolean daysFilter(ForeignerResponse foreigner) {
        return !isNull(myUtil.getDaysFromTwoDates(foreigner.getFinishDate())) &&
                (myUtil.getDaysFromTwoDates(foreigner.getFinishDate())) < 30 &&
                isNull(foreigner.getDecisionDate());
    }
```

Thank you for any tips :D

Comment: Short answer - you can't. `Sort` does not have any methods that work with comparators.

Comment: Also that boolean method looks like something designed for `filtering`, not `sorting`. Could it be that you actually need to change the filtering condition of your query?